# Drupal user hierarchical structured with taxonomy, display them in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, taxonomy

I have grouped my users with taxonomy. I managed to create a users view which displays all of them. Now I added visible filters to with which I intend to select my users by a taxonomy term. This works too but I need to have all users displayed which are selected from this term and its children.

My taxonomy structure is quite simple:

```
aaa
 -bbb
 -ccc
 -ddd
eee
 -fff
```

Now lets say that John is tagged with `bbb` he should show up when I select `aaa`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

when using [hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module you have an option to save the whole
"term lineage" so your users will be tagged with both *aaa* and *bbb* when selectting *bbb*.
you can use this "added" relationship in your user view afterwards.

another option is to use the "taxonomy term with depth" in your view filters and set it to a value greater than zero